# Seeing the directory path when using verbatimTextOutput and shinyDirChoose in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have an MRE of my app, where I am trying to choose a directory for importing csv files. I would like to have the path for a chosen directory shown in a text box below the button. So far, I get `character(0)` before I select a directory, and after I choose a directory I get the error: `object of type 'environment' is not subsettable`. Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing this? Thanks!

```
#This is the test page for step 1: set the import and export directories

library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


########## User interface ##########
ui = fluidPage(
  
  h5(strong('Select target directory for importing raw data:')),
  
  
  shinyDirButton('folderImp', 
                 'Directory Selection', 
                 'Please select a folder'),
  
  verbatimTextOutput("dir_input_text"),
  
  h5(strong('Select target directory for exporting analysis results:')),
  
  shinyDirButton('folderExp', 
                 'Directory Selection', 
                 'Please select a folder'),
  
  verbatimTextOutput("dir_output_text")
  
)#close ui, fluidpage


########## Server logic #########

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  #### Input for user browse and data upload ####
  
  switch(Sys.info()[['sysname']],
         Windows= {main_dir <- "c:/Users"},
         Linux  = {main_dir <- "/usr"},
         Darwin = {main_dir <- "~"}) #R script running on a mac
  
  shinyDirChoose(input, 
                 'folderImp', 
                 session=session,
                 roots=c(main = main_dir),
                 filetypes = c('csv'),
                 hidden = FALSE,
                 allowDirCreate = FALSE)
  
  input_pathway <- reactive({parseDirPath(session, input$folderImp) })

  output$dir_input_text <- renderPrint({ input_pathway() })
  
  
  #### Export directory for analysis results ####
  
  shinyDirChoose(input, 
                 'folderExp', 
                 session=session,
                 roots=c(main = main_dir),
                 filetypes = c('csv'),
                 hidden = FALSE,
                 allowDirCreate = FALSE)
  
  output_pathway <- reactive({parseDirPath(session, input$folderExp) })
  
  output$dir_output_text <- renderPrint({ output_pathway() })
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE**
I have it working now that so I can see the pathway after a directory is chosen, but before I choose a directory I see this error:
`$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. Does anyone have another way for me to set this up so that I don't get this error?

```
  shinyDirChoose(input, 
                 'folderImp', 
                 session=session,
                 roots=c(main = main_dir),
                 filetypes = c('csv'),
                 hidden = FALSE,
                 allowDirCreate = FALSE)
  
  input_pathway <- reactive({ input$folderImp })

  output$dir_input_text <- renderText({ paste(input_pathway()$path[-1], collapse = "/") })
  
  
  #### Export directory for analysis results ####
  
  shinyDirChoose(input, 
                 'folderExp', 
                 session=session,
                 roots=c(main = main_dir),
                 filetypes = c('csv'),
                 hidden = FALSE,
                 allowDirCreate = FALSE)
  
  output_pathway <- reactive({ input$folderExp })
  
  output$dir_output_text <- renderText({ paste(output_pathway()$path[-1], collapse = "/") })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output$dir_input_text <- renderText({ paste(input_pathway()$path[-1], collapse = "/") })` expects your reactive `input_pathway()` method to return an list-like object that has a field called "path" that can be accessed via the `$` operator. Until you select a file path, the "path" field is NULL. The same is true for `output$dir_output_text <- renderText({ paste(output_pathway()$path[-1], collapse = "/") })` in order to avoid the error you should check to see if `input_pathway()` and `output_pathway()` methods return an object that actually has a "path" field.

```r
#This is the test page for step 1: set the import and export directories

library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


########## User interface ##########
ui = fluidPage(
  
  h5(strong('Select target directory for importing raw data:')),
  
  
  shinyDirButton('folderImp', 
                 'Directory Selection', 
                 'Please select a folder'),
  
  verbatimTextOutput("dir_input_text"),
  
  h5(strong('Select target directory for exporting analysis results:')),
  
  shinyDirButton('folderExp', 
                 'Directory Selection', 
                 'Please select a folder'),
  
  verbatimTextOutput("dir_output_text")
  
)#close ui, fluidpage


########## Server logic #########

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  #### Input for user browse and data upload ####
  
  switch(Sys.info()[['sysname']],
         Windows= {main_dir <- "c:/Users"},
         Linux  = {main_dir <- "/usr"},
         Darwin = {main_dir <- "~"}) #R script running on a mac
  
  shinyDirChoose(input, 
                 'folderImp', 
                 session=session,
                 roots=c(main = main_dir),
                 filetypes = c('csv'),
                 hidden = FALSE,
                 allowDirCreate = FALSE)
  
  input_pathway <- reactive({ input$folderImp })
  
  output$dir_input_text <- renderText({ 
    ip <- input_pathway()
    ifelse('path' %in% names(ip),
           paste(ip$path[-1], collapse = "/"),
           '')
  })
  
  
  #### Export directory for analysis results ####
  
  shinyDirChoose(input, 
                 'folderExp', 
                 session=session,
                 roots=c(main = main_dir),
                 filetypes = c('csv'),
                 hidden = FALSE,
                 allowDirCreate = FALSE)
  
  output_pathway <- reactive({ input$folderExp })
  
  output$dir_output_text <- renderText({ 
    op <- output_pathway()
    ifelse('path' %in% names(op),
           paste(op$path[-1], collapse = "/"),
           '')
  })
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```